# Using UITextField inside a keyboard app extension

Tags: ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard, ios8-extension

I added textfield (keyboardTextField) on top of my custom keyboard.
I can select it and enter some text (using my custom keyboard). But it's impossible for me to select the input view of the main app back.
This line of code

```
[keyboardTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

doesn't work correctly. If someone have any workaround or any ideas, I need your help.

Comment: Check this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/34455421/1010644
I've used it in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding a button which switches the user input from the UILabel (in my case) to the (normal - iOS) UITextField in Messages f.e.

I check on a BOOL to see where to enter the user selected character.